# Expression fails when trying to hide SSRS subreport

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

In my main report I have one subreport for now. The subreport is linked and runs when I run the main report.
However, taking things step by step, I am trying to hide the subreport based on a field called "CL_Language" that has either "Spanish" or "English".

So main report runs and shows all subreports with both languages. This works.But now I am trying to hide any subreport where the "CL_Language" field.value is not "Spanish".
This is my Expression in the Visiblity property of the subreport control on main form:

```
=IIF((Fields!CL_Language.Value, "DataSet1")="Spanish",True, False)
```

I would assume I need to reference "DataSet1" since that is what the subreport is using but I get this error:

```
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIf' accepts this number of arguments.
```

So I tried without referencing the DataSet1 in the expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!CL_Language.Value="Spanish",True, False)
```

And I get all records, Spanish and English as if it doesn't see the value.
The main report has no other controls on it, is only there to show hide based on language.

I have searched for other threads that have a solution with no luck.

EDIT:
As requested in comments here is my subreport layout.
In order to create 4 printable pages per Detail row I added a ListBox to the report and added first row as Parent Group, grouped on Row ID and set Page Breaks at every instance of new group. A rectangle holds the contents of the first page. Then for the next 3 pages I "Inserted row", inside group and below.
Each one of those rows holds a rectangle with all sorts of textboxes with values from the DataSet1. So all 4 pages print for each Parent group detail. I tried setting the Visibility property in the ListBox the same way I am trying to set the subReport's Visibility property but no luck.

Comment: Can you also share sample output data of your dataset?

Comment: Thank you for asking. I have the weekend off and the stored procedure behind the DataSet1 is at work. I will try to share it sometime this weekend.
Almost positive the values in column CL_Language are "Spanish", "English", and sometimes I saw "Japanese". Don't plan to translate Japanese, just use English. I have a feeling that the subreport visibility property sets the visibility on first record, not every record.

Comment: Is there a subreport per row? You might want to share your report design too.

Comment: what about trying something like this? can use first, max..  =IIF(first(Fields!CL_Language.Value)="Spanish",True, False)

Comment: Harry, what that would do is hide the whole subreport and all it's rows based on what the first row value is. I am pretty sure "first(" is an aggregate function that excludes any other rows.